# One step picture upload

Tags: uploads, automation, media-settings

Each time I upload an image by drag & drop in the Media uploader of Wordpress, I get the options window (text-align, alt, picture name etc...).
The fact is I always use the default settings and click ok as it is always good as it is.

Is there a way, via the functions.php, to avoid showing the option window and automatically close the media uploader after the drag & drop (with Wordpress validating the default settings) ?

Thank you.